# iOS - multiple background colors on ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, background-color

I have a UIViewController with a UIScrollViewController. 
I currently color the background of my ScrollView with the following code:

```
    UIImage* backgroundImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_backg.png"];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

This works perfectly but it colors the entire view; what I would like to do is to color only say the top 50%. The rest can stay in white.
I have tried to add a UIView and color that one but it appears ON TOP of the UIScrollView, and not under it.

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the scrollview clear and then place it on top of your colored views. If you are looking for a gradient effect, there is a CAGradientLayer that is easy to work with. To accomplish what you are looking for with the gradient you could do something like this:

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    layer.colors = [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]

    layer.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
```

I haven't run this so you  may have to play with the start and endpoints to get your desired effect

Following up from the comments, programmatically it would look something like this:

```
self.view.addSubview(coloredView1)
self.view.addSubview(coloredView2) 
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

With this approach you would also have to manually build the rects

I just made a simple example project to test this. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
let coloredView1: UIView = UIView()
let coloredView2: UIView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    coloredView1.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    coloredView2.backgroundColor = .greenColor()

    self.view.addSubview(coloredView1)
    self.view.addSubview(coloredView2)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.coloredView1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.height / 2)

    self.coloredView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.coloredView1.frame.size.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height / 2)
}
```

}

Now, I bet I will get flamed on here for not using the storyboard. This really is easier with the storyboard but its easier to show in stackoverflow with code.

Comment: But how can I place the ScrollView on top of the colored views?

Comment: You can either manually place it over them via drag n' drop on the storyboard or in code you would just add your two colored views to your main view controller view first and then add your scroll view. It will stack them in the order you add them. I'll edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: See my edit answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked on Storyboard but your code was very helpful too. Once again -- thanks a lot. People like your are great.

Comment: No problem happy to help!